# Integration Test on MVC3 EF 4.2 Causes Error: The model backing the context has changed since the database was created

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, integration-testing

I'm using MVC3 EF 4.2 Code First with an existing database using the repository pattern.

When using EF Code First with an existing database no initializer is set in the Global.asax Application_Start() and the DbSet is mapped to my database tables by removing the pluralizing convention:

```
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
```

My table is called Role.

My first test passes a mock repository to the controller.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Index_Contains_All_Roles()
    {
        // Arrange - create the mock repository
        Mock<IRoleRepository> mock = new Mock<IRoleRepository>();
        mock.Setup(m => m.Roles).Returns(new Role[] {
            new Role { Id = 1, Name = "Admin" },
            new Role { Id = 2, Name = "Manager" },
            new Role { Id = 3, Name = "Examiner" },
            new Role { Id = 4, Name = "Examinee" }
        }.AsQueryable());

        // Arrange - create a controller 
        RoleController target = new RoleController(mock.Object);

        // Action
        Role[] result = ((IEnumerable<Role>)target.Index().Model).ToArray();

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Length == 4);
        Assert.AreEqual("Admin", result[0].Name);
        Assert.AreEqual("Manager", result[1].Name);
        Assert.AreEqual("Examiner", result[2].Name);
        Assert.AreEqual("Examinee", result[3].Name);            
    }
```

The first test passes.

The second test is an integration test that checks to see if the database contains the correct Roles.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Database_Contains_All_Roles()
    {
        // Arrange - create repository
        IRoleRepository roleRepository = new RoleRepository();

        // Arrange - create a controller 
        RoleController target = new RoleController(roleRepository);

        // Action
        Role[] result = ((IEnumerable<Role>)target.Index().Model).ToArray();

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Length == 4);
        Assert.AreEqual("Admin", result[0].Name);
        Assert.AreEqual("Manager", result[1].Name);
        Assert.AreEqual("Examiner", result[2].Name);
        Assert.AreEqual("Examinee", result[3].Name);
    }
```

When I run this second test I get an error:

```
The model backing the 'MyDbContext' context has changed since the database was created
```

However, viewing the actual controller in a web browser loads the correct data from the database.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It is an old issue and requires one to set the database initializer to null in Global.asax

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourDbContext>(null);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've read the posts on that issue. However I don't get any error when viewing the actual controller in a browser and the data is being loaded from the database properly. I only get the error when running the unit/(integration) test.